# BlackBerry: Hilight the background of a horizontalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry, focus

I want to hilight the background of a horizontalFieldManager when I'm scrolling. I tried this code:

```
public class HorizentalFocus extends HorizontalFieldManager{
  protected void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setBackgroundColor(isFocus() ? 4210231 : 0xFFFFFF);
    g.getFont();
    g.clear();
    super.paint(g);
  }
  protected void onFocus(int direction) {
    invalidate();
    super.onFocus(direction);
  }
  protected void onUnfocus() {
    invalidate();
    super.onUnfocus();
  }
}
```

It works but I have two problems: it doesn't hilight the entire horizontalField and I want to change the color of the text when it's focused.

[image: here's an example]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: tahnk you for editinf my post :) @dda

Comment: try to set the HorizontalFieldManager - Field.FOCUSABLE

Comment: Your code is working actually, you just need to use `HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH` while creating `HorizentalFocus` instance. And changing the text color of all the text is a little bit difficult. If you use `LabelField` for them, then modifying color on paint method depending on the focus state may be solve your problem. But then you need to set those `LabelField` as focusable. And if you do this, then moving focus from one HorizontalFieldManager to other will require more up/dowm navigation movement event.

Comment: Can you share your current code?

Comment: Actually I don't create an instance but extending HorizentalFocus.

Comment: How can you use HorizentalFocus without creating instance? :). Add a default constructor on your `HorizentalFocus` class, it will be something like this, `public HorizentalFocus () { super(HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH); }`. If you share your code it will help others to guide you.

Comment: yes finally it works due to your help.
thank you Rupak & signare I'm really grateful :).